# space-evenly (justify-content) not working on Chrome mobile

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have an issue with the `space-evenly` value for `justify-content` on Chrome mobile (it works fine on Desktop and on Firefox mobile).

I managed to produce a minimal example: [Example](http://chardetm.bitballoon.com/)

I have a flex container in a row direction and I want the elements to be spaced evenly, as intended when using `space-evenly`. It works on desktop, but on Chrome mobile (version 59 on Android), however, the elements are aligned on the left. Here is a comparison of the two: [Comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlh0u.png)

`center` and `space-around` values work as intended, however, but I really want to use `space-evenly` or an equivalent (the `flex-wrap: wrap` behavior is also important to me).

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: lightgrey;
}

.element {
  margin: 8px;
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  background: black;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try removing flex wrap. It should work

Comment: @AnmolSandal I just tried that and the problem is still there :/

Comment: Could i have the preview what you actually want for mobile :-)

Comment: @AnmolSandal do you mean what I want to do in the end?

Comment: `space-evenly`, unlike other layout options, has limited support across browsers. It is only recently introduced and has not made its way to mobile Chrome yet (or in fact, most mobile browsers don't support it). It is actually [first implemented in grid, and then ported over to flexbox](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/1167). When a browser fails to recognize this value, it falls back to `flex-start`, which is what you see on mobile Chrome.

Comment: @Terry that was my first thought, however I tried adding two rules for `justify-content`, first `space-around` and then `space-evenly`, and the result is still the same, does it mean that `space-evenly` is implemented as `flex-start` and not just "not recognized"?

Comment: You should put the most supported value last, i.e. declare `space-evenly` first, and then put your fallbacks after it. Not recognized === fallback to default, i.e. `flex-start`. It does not mean ignoring the rule.

Comment: @Terry I see, but if I put the fallbacks after they will override my first rule in all cases won't they?

Comment: What about using @supports media query?

Comment: @Terry, the problem with this value is that older versions of Chrome _do_ recognize that value, so they don't "see" the need to fallback, and `@supports` for it also would return `true`. They just fail to apply this value in other contexts than grid. It's simply a bug.

Comment: Yes I've just tried to use `@supports` but just like @IlyaStreltsyn said it returns true even on Chrome mobile.

Comment: @Terry You **always** put the _fallback_ first and then the _newer_ properties/values,... so in this case it is wrong to put the `space-evenly` first, it should be last.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no solution yet for multi-line/wrapped `space-evenly` for browsers that doesn't support it.

When using `flex-wrap: wrap` you will need to i.e. set a fixed padding on the flex container, margin on the items or use a script.

If it is possible to wrap each row you can use the pseudo elements in combination with `space-between` to achieve the exact same result as `space-evenly` give.

In below sample the `space-between` will take the *zero width* pseudo elements into account when calculating the space between, hence producing the same result.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  /* flex-wrap: wrap; */
  /* align-items: flex-start;        if "img", this will prevent it from stretching  */
  background: lightgrey;
}

.element {
  margin: 8px;
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  background: black;
}

.container::before,
.container::after {
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer! Do you know by any chance if there is a "proper" wait to detect, either with CSS media queries or with some JS, if the browser supports `space-evenly` correctly for flexboxes?

Comment: @MaverickChardet The _proper_ way is to use `@support`, though as already mentioned, for newly introduced properties/property values one always risk to get false positive's, so I recommend to wait until the majority of browsers support a given property/value.

Comment: Just a straight up swap out of `justify-content: space-evenly;` for `justify-content: space-between;` worked for me!

Answer (score 3):

Update **This seems to be a work around only for a single row**

You may fake space-evenly via margins and eventually a pseudo element.

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
}
.element,.container:before  {
  border:solid;
  margin:0 auto 0 0;
  padding:1em;
}
.container:before {
  content:'';
  border:none;
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="element">11</div>
  <div class="element">2 </div>
  <div class="element">3333</div>
  <div class="element">444</div>
</div>
```

or `nth-child` as suggested by @IlyaStreltsyn

> Or even without a pseudo element: `.element:first-child { margin: 0 auto; }`

Comment: Or even without a pseudo element: `.element:first-child { margin: 0 auto; }`.

Comment: That looks like a promising solution, but when I add `flex-wrap: wrap;` to the container and one element is sent to the next row, this element is not centered like it should be with `space-evenly`, is there a way to add this behavior?

Comment: @MaverickChardet can you produce an example to check out if there is any media querie, min-width or numbers of children or any else situation that would allow some filtering via css selectors ?

Comment: @GCyrillus I'm not sure that I understand what you're asking, but the real case scenario will be exactly like the example I gave in my first post, except that the elements will contain a `<h3>` title and a `<ul>` list.
If it's impossible to simulate `space-evenly` with `flex-wrap: wrap` in the general case, is it easier to consider that there will always be 3 elements (which is my situation at the moment even though it might change later)?

Comment: In theory, it could be solved by switching the container to `display:grid` (using `@supports`) and giving it `grid-template-columns:repeat(auto-fit,42px)`. Unfortunately, the same Chrome versions that had bug with `space-evenly` in Flexbox had also a bug with `auto-fit` in Grid (they add unused grid columns in the right). So I don't see any easy solution here, unfortunately.

Comment: I do not see any ways to solve this via CSS as son as wrapping is involved.

Comment: Would there be a way to detect if the implementation of `space-evenly` is broken for the client's browser using JS? If so I could use that instead of media queries...

Comment: @MaverickChardet I'm afraid i have no idea if thats a bug or just not implemented. If it is a bug, you won't know from js. Maybe the idea is to filter chrome mobile browsers, add a class to the container so it can apply to your mediaqueries for that specific class :( Sorry not be a much better helper at this point . filtering browser is usually not a good practice and breaks too easily to be of trust.

Comment: @MaverickChardet  Else, you could use some css/js tricks searching for a way to trigger rules only for chrome mobile , if any. See http://browserhacks.com/ (again, not a good practice :( )

Comment: @GCyrillus Don't worry thanks for taking the time! I was more thinking about a JS test on an hidden div somewhere, testing the position that the CSS gives to an element to check if it is centered or on the left, does that make sense? This way it would not test directly for the browser, but I'm wondering if there is a standardized way to do this or maybe it's a very bad practice?

Comment: @MaverickChardet To test one position is a smart idea and should be harmless ;) to my point of view

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding different values of

```
flex-direction:
```