# Vue cli 3 postcss display:flex issue

Tags: vue.js, flexbox, postcss, vue-cli, autoprefixer

**My Setup**
vue cli 3
all default config ( autoprefixer, postcss, etc )

**My problem**
with Samsung internet version > 7
a css input of display:flex is only outputting "display: ms-flexbox" and I need "display: -webkit-flex" to showup.. which won't despite any arrangement of config options and browser lists I seem to test out... not sure what I am missing here.

**The effect**
my vue spa sidenav menu has messed up layouts *only on samsung internet*, I determined that it is because it needs the -webkit-flex prefix which I cannot seem to produce

[image: Sample of my package.json setup with browserlist]

I'm sure that the "browsers" config item under "autoprefixer" is redundant, my output is the same with and without it.

Taking out "no-2009" only adds a "display: -webkit-box" that does not help out at all

Comment: Sorry for the problem in Samsung Internet. Sounds like the best way to resolve it might be to write up an issue on the [Autoprefixer repo](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer/issues) though?

Comment: thank you, I did: https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer/issues/1083

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the GitHub issue, you used `justify-content: space-evenly;` in your code example.

`justify-content: space-evenly;` is most likely your issue. It doesn't have full support across all browsers yet.

You have listed that you need to support the last 2 versions of IE. That means IE 10 & 11. I'm pretty sure that neither of those browsers support `justify-content: space-evenly;` since it was a late addition to the spec. If you test in those browsers it should look broken there as well.

Add `justify-content: space-around;` above it as a back-up. It works in almost the same way but distributes the space a bit differently.

```
ul {
  justify-content: space-around;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  /* ... The rest of the CSS... */
}
```

It needs to be placed in that order so that if the browser supports it, it will use `justify-content: space-evenly;` and if not, it will fall-back to using `justify-content: space-around;`.

It won't look as nice in the browsers that need the fallback as it does in the browsers that don't need it. It will look much better with the fallback than without it though.

Answer (score 1):

Daniel was completely correct, Samsung Browser 7.2 doesn't play well with 'justify-content: space-evenly'.. Some version of safari doesn't either ( we had someone in the office show me on their iphone but I haven't grabbed the browser version yet ).

The fix I ended up going with is a 'space-between' hack with a 'display: block' on the element's :before and :after psuedo elements.

2 links to other stack overflow posts where I learned about this are:

[How to make CSS justify-content:space-evenly fallback to space-between on Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47534216/how-to-make-css-justify-contentspace-evenly-fallback-to-space-between-on-safari)

[space-evenly (justify-content) not working on Chrome mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45612955/space-evenly-justify-content-not-working-on-chrome-mobile)

Works like a charm on all of the devices tested so far, including on samsung browser 7.2 and that same office mate's iphone browser ( whichever one it was, safari or not )

Comment: Would you mind accepting my answer as correct then? :)

Comment: even though technically my own answer is my favorite that I ended up going with, I got you lol

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove `browsers` option. You already have `browserslist` option.
2. According Can I Use, Samsung Browser doesn’t need `-webkit-` prefix.
3. Seems like you have some browser issue with flexbox here.